# How can I auto-initialise key-value in python dictionary if key-value pair does not exist, without doing IF & ELSE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary, sliding-window

How do I automatically initialize my python dictionary key-value (no idea what keys are used yet) as 1 if it does not yet exist and if it exists, just increment? I guess this concept can be used for any other logic.

---

Example:
The code below will give error because the `char_counts[char]` is **not initialised yet** for some. And I have no way of initialising this yet as I dont know what key-value pairs I will use at the start. *(Actually if I do, side-tracked, is there a convenient way in python to intialise key-value pairs in one shot aside from looping?)*
ANYWAY my main question is the below.

```
for ~some loop~:
     char_counts[char] += 1
```

This is my current workaround, which seems a little lengthy for a simple operation. **Is there better way to streamline/ shorten this?**

```
for ~some loop~:
    if char_counts.get(char, None):
          char_counts[char] += 1
    else:
          char_counts[char] = 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 3):

use defaultdict from collections library of python

```
from collections import defaultdict
char_counts = defaultdict(lambda :0)
for ~some loop~:
     char_counts[char] += 1
```

defaultdict will never throw KeyError, if key is missing that key is initialized with 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **get** method of a dictionary object.

If the key is not present in the dictionary get will return the default value to which you want to initialize the dictionary.

```
char_counts = {}
for ~some loop~:
     # If key is not present, 0 will be returned by default
     char_counts[char] = char_count.get(char,0) + 1
```

once you understand how the above code works then read about defaultdict in collections module and try the below code.

```
from collections import defaultdict
char_counts = defaultdict(int)
for ~some loop~:
     char_counts[char] += 1
```